# Is there anyway to force thread context switch, especially in some operation like ++?

Tags: java

I am wondering any way to force thread context switch? Sleep, Yield? any recommended way? Need to do some testing. Specially, can we force context switch in the ++ operation?

Comment: Can you give some more context around what you're trying to do? According to the spec, context switching shouldn't matter to behaviour (only performance if there is excessive switching)

Comment: @Bohemian: My guess is that OP is trying to simulate a race condition to either show how the code fails or verify that it doesn't fail.

Comment: @Bohemian: in a multi-threaded app with poor synchronization, a context switch most certainly can affect behavior.  Think 100 threads doing i = f(i) where f(i) = i.   Your answer can range from 1-100, depending on how the threads interleave.

Comment: @James Huh? By "context switching shouldn't matter to behaviour" I meant "code should be written properly so it works correctly no matter how much context switching happens". Also, there is nothing in the spec that requires a thread to get switched in... theoretically, it may never get switched in (although in practise it would)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try replacing

```
a++;
```

with

```
int tmp = a;
Thread.sleep(1);
a = tmp + 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Thread.yield() doesn't necessarily guarantee a switch will happen (in practice, at least, if nothing is waiting to run at that time, this is a noop).  Thread.sleep() will pretty near guarantee it - but there's no way to cause it to happen in a ++ operation, since there's no way to override the default implementation.   What are you actually trying to cause to happen?  Would causing the switch just before or after suffice?   Can you emulate what you're trying to do by setting a "watch" using your favorite IDE?